# $\int_\gamma F_1dx + F_2dy = \int_\gamma F_2dx - F_1dy = 0$ then there is a harmonic function $u$ such that $F = \nabla u$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-forms, vector-fields

Let $G \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and let $F = (F_1,F_2)$ be a smooth (which means it is $C^1)$ vector field in $G$. $F$ satisfies $$\int_\gamma F_1dx + F_2dy = \int_\gamma F_2dx - F_1dy = 0$$ for every closed and smooth path $\gamma$.

I need to prove that there exists a harmonic function $u: G \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $F = \nabla u$.

I wasn't sure what to do, so I just started trying different things. I think there is a theorem that if for every closed path $\gamma$ it satisfies $\int_\gamma \omega = 0$, then $\omega$ is an exact differential form.

If I write $\omega_1 = F_1dx + F_2dy$ and $\omega_2 = F_2dx - F_1dy$ then both are exact and there exist $u_1,u_2: G \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\omega_1 = du_1$ and $\omega_2 = du_2$

From here I am not so sure what to do. I think I can also use Green's theorem here, but I am not sure how it helps.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

By Stokes with the first integral, for every closed disk $D$, 
$$\int_D{d\omega_1}=0.$$

From this follows that $\omega_1$ is closed. Since it is a $1$-form, and provided $G$ *is simply connected*, $\omega_1$ is exact and there exists some $u$ such that $\omega_1=du$, ie $F=\nabla u$.

For the same reason, $\omega_2$ is closed, and you can easily check that $-d\omega_2=(\nabla \cdot F)dx \wedge dy$, thus $0=\nabla \cdot F=\Delta u$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have only studies $1$-forms. So I don't really understand the second part of your answer

Comment: Which part shall I explain? Do you know exterior derivatives of $1$-forms? Stokes’ theorem? Why closedness implies exactness for $1$-forms in a simply connected domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: I didn't learn Stokes' theorem but I learned some other claims. I understand that why $\omega_1$ is exact and equal to $du$, and so $ F = \nabla u$. But I didn't understand how you used $\omega_2$ to conclude that $u$ is harmonic. I didn't really understand anything of the things you did with $\omega_2$.

Comment: In the exact same way as I proved $\omega_1$ to be closed, I can prove that $\omega_2$ is closed. Now, if you write explcitly $d\omega_2$, you find the divergence of $F$ ie the Laplacian of $u$: thus said Laplacian is zero and $u$ is harmonic.

Comment: Could you write the calculations please? I am still not sure I get it

Comment: $d\omega_2=d(F_2dx)-d(F_1dy)=dF_2 \wedge dx + F_2d(dx)-dF_1 \wedge dy-F_1d(dy)$. Now, $d(dx)=d(dy)=0$, thus $d\omega_2=dF_2 \wedge dx - dF_1 \wedge dy$. $dF_2 \wedge dx=\left(\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x}dx\right)\wedge dx+\left(\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial y}dy\right) \wedge dx$. Since $dx \wedge dx=0$, it follows $dF_2 \wedge dx=-\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial y}dx \wedge dy$. Similarly, $-dF_1 \wedge dy=\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x}dx \wedge dy$.

Comment: I am sorry. but I don't know what is the symbol $\wedge $, I never seen it used

Comment: I managed to solve it with only 1-forms using the fact that if $\omega_2$ is exact it is necessarily closed